# Асинхронное выполнение опроса нескольких REST или SOAP API

Tags: php, api, rest, php7, асинхронность

Доброго времени суток!
В двух словах:
Есть ресурс, который по средствам обращения к веб-сервисам поставщиков (REST или SOAP) динамически формирует, уже не посредственно на своей стороне, прайс-листы для конечного пользователя.

На данный момент опрос поставщиков идет синхронно, по средствам php один за другим.

Задаем пустой массив->Опрашиваем первого поставщика->ответ в массив, опрашиваем второго->ответ в массив...

так формируется массив. Далее сортируется, фильтруется... и в конце получаем 
готовый массив который уже и выдаем пользователю.

Так вот, в последнее время список подключенных поставщиков существенно увеличилось, а соответственно опросов стало еще больше и суммарное время на получение первоначального массива увеличилось в разы.
Чисто теоретически понимаю, что выполняя асинхронный опрос всех поставщиков, мы получим потраченное время на общий опрос равное самому наибольшему времени ответа от одного из поставщиков, а не сумме времени ответов от каждого.
Но не понимаю как правильно можно реализовать такой метод.
Опрашивать всех сразу, ждать последний ответ, а после формировать единый ("суммарный") массив из всех пришедших ответов.
Прошу заранее прощения если задаю вопрос не корректно.
Заранее благодарю за отзывчивость!

Comment: Асинхронные запросы умеет делать `cURL` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-init.php или можно воспользоваться библиотекой, которая так же может делать асинхронные запросы, к примеру https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle